How to use stix and unicode-math in latex
I want to switch to Neo Euler with its nice looking integral symbols. But I dont know what am I doing. After I added \usepackage{unicode-math} I gets errors that tells me it do not work with pdflatex. And if I use \usepackage{stix} it will cause an error too many symbol declared. I am not sure what to do can someone help me?
Thanks！
 \documentclass[12pt, reqno]{amsart}
\usepackage[margin=0.5in]{geometry}    
\geometry{letterpaper}       
%\geometry{landscape}                % Activate for for rotated page geometry
\usepackage[parfill]{parskip}    % Activate to begin paragraphs with an empty line rather than an indent
\usepackage{pdfsync}  %leaves makers for tex searching
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{euler}
\usepackage[pdftex,bookmarks]{hyperref}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{setspace}
\usepackage[mathscr]{euscript}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}
\usepackage{listings}
\usepackage{setspace} 
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usepackage{newpxtext}
\usepackage[euler-digits]{eulervm}
\usepackage[many]{tcolorbox}
\pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
\usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
\tcbuselibrary{theorems}


Start by removing the unnecessary packages and options. For instance, pdfsync has been obsolete (and deprecated) for more than 20 years.

you don't really say what you want to do, you could use unicode-math and the original stix opentype math font with lualatex, or if you want to stick to pdflatex use stix2 package and teh version converted to 8 bit tex fonts. in either case remove clashing font packages that are loading unused fonts putting you over the limit.

Thank you, I want to be able to use the upright version of the integral symbol which I need to either  add stix  package or math-unicode. and I cant figure out how to do that. I managed to delete some packagaes as suggested and the "too many symbol declared " error went away but my integral is still not upright.

@RemuX You can use the edit thing at the bottom of your post to update it with your slimmer code.
